# Visual Studio is not seeing my new code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to debug in Visual Studio, and it doesn't seem to see the changes that I've made, it's as if it is debugging the old code that I have replaced.

I've done a full clean of the solution, as well as manually deleted all obj and bin folders, restarted  Visual Studio and the computer, but it keeps happening.

Is there somewhere else that the old code might be residing that Visual Studio could be running from?

Comment: Are you attaching the debugger to deployed code?  If so, have you tried _deploying the new code_?

Comment: Check the Output Console of Visual Studio. To me it sounds like your project is not deployed to the simulator/device.

Comment: Have you got the Build check box checked in Build --> Configuration manager and you are running debug mode.

Comment: I sometimes have this problem with webservices running in IIS express. I open a the same webservice in another branch, run it, but it's still using the webservices of another branch.

Comment: What type of application is this?

Comment: How do you know your new code is not running? When I was first starting out, I would often swear up and down that my new code wasn't being run, but would later find out, that what I thought my code was doing, simply wasn't doing that which I thought.  Check your code.

Comment: Try going to your Android project properties and uncheck `Use Fast Deployment` under `Android Options`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @HansKesting it's a mobile POS application, written withXamarin Forms but currently testing on Android.

Comment: @DontThinkJustGo it was definitely not running the new code, - breakpoints in the constructor of a view that appeared on screen were not hit. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments and answers. It was definitely not running my code, even breakpoints in the constructor of a view that appeared on the device were not being hit.

In the end I removed the application from the target device, and then redeployed. After that things started working normally.

The only possible reason I can think of is that I had recently made a new solution file, which although it referenced most of the same files, was slightly different from the original one.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you should do when you suspect that your new code isn't being run is add an identifiable indicator, such as printing to the console with `Debug.Write()` or showing a toast when clicking a button or something. Make your indicator as such there will be *no way* to be unsure whether or not the new code is running.

I have been in many situations where it *appeared* new code was not running, but its often just something as simple as my change not having the effect I expected.

In the *very rare* event that your new code is not being run, here are some suggestions to try:

- Restart your device(if you are using one) as well as clear any cache/data associated with the app on the device.
- Make sure that ADB is actually connected to the device, open up an ADB console and try opening a shell to the device. If it fails you may need to restart the ADB process
- Try running with both `Fast Deployment` and without; you can find this in your `Android Project Properties`
- As a *very very very* last resort, make a new project and move all your files over to it. This should be a non-existent solution, and I would recommend trying your hardest to solve your problem some other way. But if your project is brand new with only like 1 or 2 classes this option is more realistic.

Debugging issues like this can be a huge PITA, but are very fixable so keep your head up!

Comment: Your first suggestion is what helped me many times in this situation. **Manually uninstall** the app from your device, this way you can be 100% sure that new code is now in your app!